# Spring Security database authorization

Tags: java, forms, spring, security, authentication

Iam attempring to use Spring Security 3.1.3 to secure a web aplication.

Currently I have setup a simple login form that is working with users hardcoded on the security-app-context.xml. Now I'm trying to move on to have spring validate the users from a database and thats were I'm having problems.
From what I got so far I need to place a bean on applicationContext.xml for the datasource and then reference that datasource on the security-app-context.xml file:

aplicationcontex.xml:

```
<bean id="dataSource"
  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

  <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/webproject" />
  <property name="username" value="root" />
  <property name="password" value="root" />
</bean>
```

security-app-context.xml

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>            
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

But when I do so authenticating users from the database does not work. No exceptions are being raised.

There are two tables on the database, user (username,password,enabled) and authorities(username, roleName). Am I missing something?

Comment: I have tested and I can retrieve data from the DB using DB report on the login page .jsp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database schema is wrong, `authorities` doesn't have a `roleName` column but a `authority` column instead. The required SQL statements as per the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/appendix-schema.html) are:

```
create table users(
    username varchar_ignorecase(50) not null primary key,
    password varchar_ignorecase(50) not null,
    enabled boolean not null);

create table authorities (
    username varchar_ignorecase(50) not null,
    authority varchar_ignorecase(50) not null,
    constraint fk_authorities_users foreign key(username) references users(username));
    create unique index ix_auth_username on authorities (username,authority);
```

Oh, and whenever you run into troubles with Spring Security I recommend you [enable debug logging](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/start-here.html) - lots of valuable information there.

Comment: My schema was incorrect, thank you for pointing out! I remember following instructions from spring documentation, were the table names changed on SS newer versions?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to leave a comment.I'm not intended to give an accurate answer anyway.

I have a couple of guesses:

- Are you sure that database column-name for *role* is roleName? not authority? maybe Spring looks for some default name if not provided explicitly . This line will define the exact query you expect it to run:

  ```
  <authentication-manager>
              <authentication-provider>
                          <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" 
                 users-by-username-query="
                    select username,password, enabled 
                    from users where username=?" 
                 authorities-by-username-query="
                    select u.username, ur.authority from users u, user_roles ur 
                    where u.user_id = ur.user_id and u.username=?" 
                   />
              </authentication-provider>
  </authentication-manager>
  ```
- Did you add security filters to your web.xml?
- Or perhaps your tables should have some default name, like **users** ??